# Ignore error required select file

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want use from multiple upload image in codeigniter but problem is here that if if don't select image for upload return is false in case i want if don't select image for upload it redirect to my url(just ignore from error required select file). how can fix it in function `go_upload`?

My function:

```
<?php
function go_upload($field = 'userfile')
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    // Is $_FILES[$field] set? If not, no reason to continue.
    if (!isset($_FILES[$field]['name'][0])) {
        $CI->upload->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        $num_files    = count($_FILES[$field]['name']) - 1;
        $file_list    = array();
        $error_hold   = array();
        $error_upload = FALSE;
    }

    // Is the upload path valid?
    if (!$CI->upload->validate_upload_path()) {
        // errors will already be set by validate_upload_path() so just return FALSE
        return FALSE;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_files; $i++) {
        //            $fname = $_FILES[$field]['name'][$i];
        //            echo "$fname\n\n<br><br>\n\n";

        $error_hold[$i] = FALSE;

        // Was the file able to be uploaded? If not, determine the reason why.
        if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i])) {
            $error = (!isset($_FILES[$field]['error'][$i])) ? 4 : $_FILES[$field]['error'][$i];

            switch ($error) {
                case 1: // UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
                    $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_exceeds_limit';
                    break;
                case 2: // UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
                    $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_exceeds_form_limit';
                    break;
                case 3: // UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
                    $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_partial';
                    break;
                case 4: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
                    $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_file_selected';
                    break;
                case 6: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR
                    $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_temp_directory';
                    break;
                case 7: // UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
                    $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_unable_to_write_file';
                    break;
                case 8: // UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
                    $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_stopped_by_extension';
                    break;
                default:
                    $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_file_selected';
                    break;
            }

            return FALSE;
        }

        // Set the uploaded data as class variables
        $CI->upload->file_temp = $_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i];
        $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->file_name = $_FILES[$field]['name'][$i];
        $CI->upload->file_size = $_FILES[$field]['size'][$i];
        $CI->upload->file_type = preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $_FILES[$field]['type'][$i]);
        $CI->upload->file_type = strtolower($CI->upload->file_type);
        $CI->upload->file_ext  = $CI->upload->get_extension($_FILES[$field]['name'][$i]);

        // Convert the file size to kilobytes
        if ($CI->upload->file_size > 0) {
            $CI->upload->file_size = round($CI->upload->file_size / 1024, 2);
        }

        // Is the file type allowed to be uploaded?
        if (!$CI->upload->is_allowed_filetype()) {
            $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_filetype';
        }

        // Is the file size within the allowed maximum?
        if (!$CI->upload->is_allowed_filesize()) {
            $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_filesize';
        }

        // Are the image dimensions within the allowed size?
        // Note: This can fail if the server has an open_basdir restriction.
        if (!$CI->upload->is_allowed_dimensions()) {
            $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_dimensions';
        }

        // Sanitize the file name for security
        $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->clean_file_name($CI->upload->file_name);

        // Remove white spaces in the name
        if ($CI->upload->remove_spaces == TRUE) {
            $CI->upload->file_name = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $CI->upload->file_name);
        }

        /*
         * Validate the file name
         * This function appends an number onto the end of
         * the file if one with the same name already exists.
         * If it returns false there was a problem.
         */
        $CI->upload->orig_name = $CI->upload->file_name;

        if ($CI->upload->overwrite == FALSE) {
            $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->set_filename($CI->upload->upload_path, $CI->upload->file_name);

            if ($CI->upload->file_name === FALSE) {
                $error_hold[$i] = TRUE;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Move the file to the final destination
         * To deal with different server configurations
         * we'll attempt to use copy() first.  If that fails
         * we'll use move_uploaded_file().  One of the two should
         * reliably work in most environments
         */
        if (!@copy($CI->upload->file_temp, $CI->upload->upload_path . $CI->upload->file_name)) {
            if (!@move_uploaded_file($CI->upload->file_temp, $CI->upload->upload_path . $CI->upload->file_name)) {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_destination_error';
            }
        }

        /*
         * Run the file through the XSS hacking filter
         * This helps prevent malicious code from being
         * embedded within a file.  Scripts can easily
         * be disguised as images or other file types.
         */
        if ($CI->upload->xss_clean == TRUE) {
            $CI->upload->do_xss_clean();
        }

        if ($error_hold[$i]) {
            $error_upload = TRUE;

            //                echo $error_hold[$i];
        } else {
            if ($imageVar = $this->multiple_image_properties($CI->upload->upload_path . $CI->upload->file_name)) {
                $file_list[] = array(
                    'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                    'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path . $CI->upload->file_name,
                    'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                    'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext,
                    'image_type' => $imageVar->image_type,
                    'height' => $imageVar->height,
                    'width' => $imageVar->width
                );
            } else {
                $file_list[] = array(
                    'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                    'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path . $CI->upload->file_name,
                    'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                    'type' => $CI->upload->file_type,
                    'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext
                );
            }
        }

        // For debugging

        /*            
        if (strlen($error_hold[$i]) > 1) {
        print_r($error_hold);
        }
        */
    } // end for loop

    // Add error display for individual files        
    if ($error_upload) {
        $this->set_error($error_hold);
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return $file_list;
    }
}
?>
```

My CI_Controller:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; // server directory
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; // by extension, will check for whether it is an image
$config['max_size']    = '1000'; // in kb
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';

$this->upload->initialize($config);
$this->load->library('Multi_upload');

$files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();    
if ( ! $files )
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());                         
    print_r($error);
    return false;
}
else
{
$data3 = array();
foreach ($files as $idx => $name) {
    //var_dump($name['name']);
    $data3[] = array(
        'relation' => $query_hi->id,
        'images' => $name['name'],
    );
};
}
$this->db->insert_batch('hotel_image', $data3);
redirect('admin/residence/insert');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try taking a look at what in inside of the.

```
$_FILES
```

Array, that is the array that php starts when a post forum also has an image. If your controller checks there to make sure there is an image or not should be a good way to avoid that error.

Comment: Well, i not have always select file, i sometimes select file that have `return true;` and sometimes don't select file that have `return false;`, now what do i do that in each two has `return true;` but there are error?